# How to send following type of paramters in ios?

Tags: ios, swift

This is the request parameters i am using in postman with raw request.

```
{
    "details":
    {
        "fullName":"manish", 
        "password":"123456", 
        "email":"manish@gmail.com", 
        "mobile":"",
        "dob":"", 
        "profilePic": ""
    }
}
```

Please tell how can i set parameters for this request.
I tried the following to set parameters but it also didn't work.

```
let parameters = ["details": [
            "fullName": "manish",
            "password": "123456",
            "email": "manish@gmail.com",
            "mobile": "",
            "dob": "",
            "profilePic": ""
            ]] as [String : Any]
```

Please help.

Comment: is that a post request?

Comment: yes. its a post request.

Comment: Does Mr. Duncan's code work for you?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like everything about your code is correct except the type. You have a dictionary of dictionaries where everything is a `String`.

Change the last part to `as [String : [String : String]`